# Import VMware Image to Azure - Credentials?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I try to create a Virtual Computer in Azure Portal from VMWare Image. I worked with this tutorials:

- https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/#uploadvm
  (german)
- https://buildwindows.wordpress.com/2015/12/20/how-to-add-a-nic-to-an-azure-virtual-machine-arm/
  (english)

In the german tutorial you´ll find

```
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmConfig -Windows -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
```

To get $cred i used:

```
$cred = Get-Credentials
```

a login windows will appear to enter credentials

What kind of credentials i have to enter here? The credentials of the Image or Azure? In what format i have to enter it? I tried Computername\User and password (e.g. ARES\Administrator and the password.

### EDIT 1

with the machine credentials MyMachineName\Administrator i got the following error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $cred = Get-Credential

Cmdlet Get-Credential an der Befehlspipelineposition 1
Geben Sie Werte für die folgenden Parameter an:
Credential
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmConfig -Windows -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm
New-AzureRmVM : Windows admin user name cannot be more than 20 characters long, end with a period(.), or contain the following characters: \ / " [ ] : | < > + = ; , ? * @.
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : ''
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:11
+ $result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locatio ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

### Edit 2

After the tip to read the example of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603843.aspx i got this one. My user is Administrator, but i got the message, ist no allowed?!

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Administrator", $SecurePassword);
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $AvailabilitySet = Get-AzureRmAvailabilitySet -ResourceGroupName "KGSCloud"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $vmName = "titan"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $computerName = "TITAN"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmConfig -Windows -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $Credential -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm
New-AzureRmVM : The Admin Username specified is not allowed.
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: Bad Request
OperationID : ''
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:11
+ $result = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $locatio ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Can someone help me?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

For `Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem` you will need to enter the credentials of the virtual machine. So the format would be the local administrator account and password at this stage.

Comment: Have you followed the example here to make sure your passing credentials properly: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603843.aspx

Comment: oh, i didnt see that. i will try it again with this example. thx u